# mysql keyword search fulltext

Tags: php, mysql

I am looking for a keyword search on my website and having a bit of difficulties

```
$q = "SELECT * from post WHERE post_k like '%".$_GET['s']."%'";
```

website url after search is **website.com/?s=keyword**

I am not getting fulltext searches. For example if I search for robin I can get results from batman because they both have n in the word. I am looking for a search that if I type robin I will only get results from robin.

Thanks

Comment: I might be repeating myself with regexp. But that would do the job.

Comment: `website.com?s=ROBERT'; DROP TABLE students`

Comment: Very important. Please read this: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet

Answer (score 5):

You need to use `MATCH AGAINST` with `FULLTEXT INDEX`.

```
CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX search_index ON post (post_k);
```

Then your query would be more like (Example using prepared statements with MySQLi):

```
$query = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM post WHERE MATCH(post_k) AGAINST(?)");
$query->bind_param('s', $_GET['s']);
```

Comment: how would i fully type that out?

Comment: More information here: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php